# How do i rewrite this url address

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL that looks like this http://domain.com/index.php/view/test. How do i rewrite it so it doesn't have `index.php/view` in it. I just want it to look like http://domain.com/test. I want users to be able to type that short url directly in the browser

I tried the following in `.htaccess` but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php/view/
```

I'm running php 5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/index.php/view/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/view/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/view/$1 [L]
```

Would do it if I understand you correctly.

Comment: This is giving an Internal Server Error

Comment: Wow it really shouldn't, I've added the `[L]` flag I don't suppose that fixes the problem?

Comment: Does adding the `RewriteBase` statement help?

Comment: I think the problem must be elsewhere, I've just set this up quickly and tried it, the rewrite happens as expected: `/test` was forwarded internally to `index.php/view/test`

Comment: Hmm, What do you think it could be. Where do i look.

Comment: I'd start by going to the top of `index.php` and putting `echo 'This works'; exit();`, if the page displays then you know the problem is somewhere in your PHP code. Otherwise it's probably a server configuration issue